# Is it possible to nest associative arrays in Perl

Tags: perl

Just an academic question regarding nesting capabilities.

For example:

```
%inner = (1, "monday", 2, "tuesday"...);
%outer = ("hello", 1, "days", %inner);
```

Comment: Yes — you can nest arrays (or, at least, references to arrays) more or less arbitrarily.  And that applies to both ordinary arrays and hashes (associative arrays).

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc

Comment: For a gentle tutorial intro to this topic, see: [Mark's very short tutorial about references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut)

Answer (score 11):

The value in a hash is always a scalar, but it can be a hash reference.

```perl
my %outer = (hello => 1,
             days  => \%inner);
```

Or you can enter an anonymous hash directly:

```perl
my %outer = (hello => 1,
             days  => {1 => 'Monday',
                       2 => 'Tuesday',
                       ...});
```

Withour a reference, the "nested" hash is flattened, which is sometimes used to override default values:

```
my %conf = (%default, %specific);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could always just have tried it. If you pass a reference of the first hash you can store it like a nested structure.

```perl
use Data::Dumper;

%inner = (1, "monday", 2, "tuesday"); 
%outer = ("hello", 1, "days", \%inner);
print(Dumper(\%outer));
print($outer{'days'}{2});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => 1,
          'days' => {
                      '2' => 'tuesday',
                      '1' => 'monday'
                    }
        };
tuesday
```